# awk to improve Formatting File :

Tags: awk

Please help to improve the below formatting command as it is taking lot of time, Input file delimiter is `**` separated, `22.00` Million rows and `87` columns.
In output need to choose only `2` columns `print substr($3,0,15),substr($4,3,10)` & comma separated delimiter.

```
time zcat hlr*.gz | awk -F"**" '{OFS=","; print substr($3,0,15),substr($4,3,10)}' >Op_Formatted.csv
```

When I am running the above command in uname: Linux is taking 5 Hours 32 Minutes

```
real    319m48.471s
user    313m49.924s
sys 1m32.803s
```

whereas  uname: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 is taking 16 minutes only

```
real    16m52.823s
user    17m35.485s
sys 0m6.986s
```

Sample Input:

```
2**000001**804421890831817F**819200000068FFFF**00** 0** 21- 10** 72- 1** 90- 32** 51- 1** 54- 1** 55- 1** 126- 5** 141- 44** 143- 1** 140- 58** 105- 0** 106- 0** 121- 4** 147- 1** 152- 1** 34- 0** 33- 4** 9- 1** 10- 1** 38- 1** 110- 1** 2- 1** 4- 1** 5- 1** 6- 1** 8- 1** 43- 1** 44- 1** 45- 1** 46- 1** 85- 0** 86- 4** 42- 0** 47- 0** 48- 0** 49- 0** 112- 1**9607500248789478**
2**000002**804421812449266F**819200000227FFFF**00** 0** 21- 10** 72- 1** 90- 32** 51- 1** 54- 1** 55- 1** 126- 5** 141- 44** 143- 1** 140- 5** 105- 0** 106- 0** 121- 4** 147- 1** 152- 1** 34- 0** 33- 7** 9- 1** 10- 1** 38- 1** 110- 1** 2- 1** 4- 1** 5- 1** 6- 1** 8- 1** 43- 1** 44- 1** 45- 1** 46- 1** 85- 0** 86- 4** 42- 0** 47- 0** 48- 0** 49- 0** 112- 1**4592140525164919**
2**000003**804421830628518F**819200000312FFFF**00** 0** 21- 10** 72- 1** 90- 35** 51- 1** 54- 1** 55- 1** 126- 5** 141- 44** 140- 58** 105- 0** 106- 0** 121- 4** 147- 1** 152- 1** 34- 0** 33- 4** 9- 1** 10- 1** 38- 1** 110- 1** 2- 1** 4- 1** 5- 1** 6- 1** 8- 1** 43- 1** 44- 1** 45- 1** 46- 1** 85- 0** 86- 4** 42- 0** 47- 0** 48- 0** 49- 0** 112- 1**6570980506503001**
```

Sample Output:

```
804421890831817,9200000068
804421812449266,9200000227
804421830628518,9200000312
```

Comment: `-F'**'` means `the letter * repeated zero or more times`. That will matter if you have an empty field because `a****b` will be seen as 2 fields instead of 3. You should be using `-F'*[*]'` or similar. Also, the 2nd argument for `substr()` is the starting character position. The 1st character position is 1, not 0. Using `0` "works" because it's an invalid position so awk does the best it can with it and assumes you must've meant `1` instead. I don't know if that'll slow it down or not, but just use the correct value of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your linux env has memory issue or disk I/O read issue. I am fine in my environment.

Here are some suggestions.

First, put OFS outside, in your command, OFS is defined again on every line.

```
zcat hlr*.gz | awk '{print substr($3,0,15),substr($4,3,10)}' FS="**" OFS="," >Op_Formatted.csv >Op_Formatted.csv
```

If the position is not changed, try this:

```
zcat hlr*.gz | awk '{print substr($0,12,15) "," substr($0,32,10)}' >Op_Formatted.csv >Op_Formatted.csv
```

Test with first command on a 3000 lines file

```
real    0m0.297s
user    0m0.249s
sys     0m0.046s
```

Test with second command:

```
real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m0.030s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BMW for suggestions, I am running the suggested commands and update you once the job is done ..

Comment: +1 for moving the setting of OFS outside but I'd do it with `-v`. I suspect printing an explicit comma will be slower than setting OFS because the former will invoke string concatenation before the print and that's the slowest operation in awk, even slower than I/O. For the time stats - did you run each command 3 or 4 times first to remove any caching impact?

Comment: if print "," directly with first command, save about 0.05s (3000 lines)

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton & BMV for suggestions, It seems that 2nd command is running very fast than 1st command , Time taken reduced from 6 Hours to 8 Minutes :: time zcat hlr*.gz | awk '{print substr($0,12,15) "," substr($0,32,10)}' >Op_Formatted_Tech_New.csv >Op_Formatted_Tech_New.csv

real    8m58.206s
user    8m6.186s
sys     0m20.700s

time zcat hlr*.gz | awk '{print substr($3,0,15),substr($4,3,10)}' FS="**" OFS="," >Op_Formatted_Tech_New22.csv >Op_Formatted_Tech_New22.csv

real 386m32.201s